In Godot 4.2 what is the proper way to get the size of a mesh instance?
I am procedurally generating a maze with various sized objects and they need to be placed by the center position. In order to do that I need to get the dimensions to find the center because my algorithm I'm using generates the position based on the center of the object. But if I change the objects size I want it to recalculate where the center of the mesh is for proper placement.
By the way I am instantiating .tscn files so not sure if that makes a difference or not. In Godot3 I believe you used get_size() or something similar, but I can't figure out what it is in Godot4 and can't seem to find it in the documentation. I am new to Godot and really new to Godot 4 so please be gentle. I also searched several forums for this answer and came up with nothing. It might be how I'm wording it so if it fits into a category admins, please move it there!
Thanks!
